# No puedo reiniciar servidor MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, aws, server, base-de-datos

Trato de reiniciar mi servidor de BD y me sale el siguiente mensaje

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-0-80 ~]$ sudo service mariadb restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart mariadb.service
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Al colocar el detalle

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si busco la información del journalctl -xe

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Su ayuda por favor

Comment: Sigue las instrucciones del mensaje y revisa journalctl -xe. Edita tu pregunta e incluye lo que sale en ese log relacionado con el fallo

Answer (score -1):

Por favor puedes enviar el resultado del comando `service mariadb status`.

¿Tienes alguna base de datos?

Si no tienes ninguna base de datos prueba a borrar todo lo que tengas en `/var/lib/mysql` y ejecutar `mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql` esto genera de nuevo la estructura.

Si no consigues que arranque el servicio prueba a reinstalar mariadb.

Un saludo.

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: Tengo una BD y no quiero perder nada de su contenido. Me recomendaron matar el proceso, pero como puedo revisar todos los procesos e identificarlo para poder matarlo y volver a reiniciarlo

Comment: Para visualizar los procesos puedes usar ps -eall y luego utilizar killall y el nombre del proceso o utilizar kill junto con el pid del proceso para eliminarlo. Pero yo creo que ese no es tu problema, ya que el proceso de mariadb no esta arrancado. Prueba a mostrar el service mariadb status y sube imagen para ver si indica algo, también si puedes busca en los logs de mariadb supongo que estarán en /var/log/

Comment: @Pastor justo en la primera imagen lo que coloque es el status del mariadb.
No hay alguna forma que pueda parar y volver a levantar el mariadb? 
intenté con restart, force restart pero nada.